# Bubbles like smoke ..2D effect. How to?

Tags: game-engine, game-physics

I'm new to game programming..What I want to achieve is an effect like bubbles which behaves like smoke in 2D. I will explain...I don't want a realistic effect or fog. I want to do something like bubbles in the background which fly in the sky and become bigger and bigger and move like they are suspended in space. They become bigger until they reach some size.
Something like this[image]

What is the best way to achieve this ? Is there somewhere in the skynet?  Some examples or ready effects?  Where to start ? I program in Java but even though the examples are in C++ or other languages it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Your question is very broad and it is hard to see what you actually want. The image with `mspaint` touches isn't really helpful either. Try a little harder.

Comment: the image I think is very explanatory..the balls grows and go up like smoke. My problem is how to give to the balls the effect like they are closer and closer to the user and at the same time go up not in a linear manner but like dancing.

Comment: Are you using sprites, meshes, particles? Do you want them textured (1D, 2D, 3D), shaders, procedural 3D textures from shaders? Should they move up, down, not move, be in front of everything, behind anything? You need to give *some kind of detail*.

Comment: simple sprites..I'm talking about 2D graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a method to draw already, like openGL or Canvas.
You probably want to create the balls as objects with variables like x,y,size etc. Then when you draw it, make sure you updated these variables, by for example increase the size if you want it to become bigger, or the x if you want it to move to the right.

Other option is to create an animated image like a .gif ofcoarse.